# Data Transfer Between Serial Port and Device using Perl Win32::SerialPort module

Tags: perl, serial-port

I am developing a Perl script to transfer data between Bluetooth firmware (BT connected through USB) and test equipment (connected through a serial port). I am using the Perl module `Win32::SerialPort`. I can get data from Equipment in special ASCII format ( ☻ Black Smiley..♥ Black heart...). When I convert it back to hex I get the opcode that my firmware can process. In return BT firmware sends a command complete opcode back.

Problem starts here... When I try to write back to Serial Port using $PortObj->write(opcode(hex)) the test equipment does not recognize it.  What should I do here?

Comment: The error is likely at line 42. Had you provided a small sample of the program you're writing, one would be able to pinpoint the problem better. Without it, one can only wonder academically on what may cause the problem. My guess is you're not sending the serial port what you're thinking you're sending.

Comment: ok I guess pack function in perl works for me :).. @input=(0x04,0x0e,0x04,0x01,0x03,0x0c,0x00);
 $ascii = pack("C*", @input);
 
 print "the value is $ascii";


 $PortObj->write($ascii)|| die "Can't write to $PortName: $^E\n";;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok I guess pack function in perl works for me :)..

@input=(0x04,0x0e,0x04,0x01,0x03,0x0c,0x00);

$ascii = pack("C*", @input);

print "the value is $ascii";

$PortObj->write($ascii)|| die "Can't write to $PortObj: $^E\n";